# How to default all prints to black and white from corporate print server?

Tags: printing, network-printers

I have a networked printer which all request go through a print server at my corporate office. When I print anything locally it prints in black and white, when it comes over the print server, it prints in color. I can't get my corporate office to install the printer driver for my printer, they only want to install HP drivers.

Is there a way to make sure everything that comes over the print server is print in black and white, even if I don't have access to the corporate print server?

Comment: It is not clear on why you want jobs to go thru the print server if you are already able to print to your specific printer locally. Can you please explain this.

Comment: We print orders locally, but orders print from our corporate call center as well. Any orders printed locally, will print in black and white, anything that came through, from the call center, would use their print server settings, and print in color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to have my corporate IT department install the HP Laser Jet 4 print driver on the corporate print server. The HP Laser Jet 4 print driver, is a Gray-scale driver, so it will always print in Black and White.

Hope this helps someone else who might run into this problem.